# Delphi, Integrate or combine or join cookie to internet browser

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I am using Mozilla firefox to logged-in a particular website, and there are times that I used Internet explorer to logged-in also in the same website.

I'm also using TWebbrowser from Delphi(mywebbrowser), and when I point the URL to navigate, it points that Im already logged-in from Internet Explorer,  But I want to use the cookie of Mozilla Firefox, so if Im logged-in to a website using Firefox and Use my own WebBrowser I will not have to logged-in anymore.

Just want to ask if possible to set the cookie of Mozilla Firefox to Internet Explorer will solved?  OR there's a lot more than that?

thanks

Comment: Why don't you just try it and find out?

Comment: @RobKennedy Im asking before testing, because I don't really code a super good.  thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TWebBrowser is a wrapper for IE's ActiveX/COM object, which shares the same core with the standalone IE browser, which includes cookies.

For what you are asking, you would have to manually access and export Firefox's cookies (I don't know if Firefox has an API for that but I doubt it, so you will have to search online for more details) and re-format them as text files saved into IE's cookies folder.  Neither Firefox nor IE will do the export/import for you.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I know how to export Firefox cookies(sqlite) to IE cookies Folder, But is that it? Ones I have exported the cookies from Firefox to IE cookies folder, that will do to solved? Just the cookies?  I think the Firefox cookies.sqlite has no username and password stored, it is stored in different sqlite file.  So with the cookies.sqlite will do the rest? thanks

Comment: cookies don't have usernames/password associated with them, only urls, timestamps, and a few other behavioral attributes. Their content is merely name=value data that is arbitrarily created by webservers. cookie content may contain usernames/password, but that is not something your client code needs to deal with.  Just copy the cookie data as-is from Firefox to IE.

Comment: I don't know how Firefox stores its cookies, but IE cookies are just plain text files.  So *if* you can read FireFox's cookie data, then you can certainly copy it to IE cookies.